# Hibernate Dynamic Field Selection

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, entity

I have an entity with 150 columns. But I want to show only 10-15 columns. Those columns could be dynamic. I shall have option to specify which are the columns to be fetched.

Since performance is considered in this, how can I fetch only the selected field across the entity?

How to achieve this? Anything like dynamic projection possibilities? Pls help...

Comment: With Hibernate only I don't think its possible (not easy at least). Do you have QueryDSL in your project? If not - is adding QueryDSL  an option ? If so I could show you an example of such 'dynamic' projection.

Comment: Dear rgrebski. I was able to get the result using ProjectionList. The thing is, its coming as an object[]. Unable to retrieve it as entity object from the criteria.list().